# Best Format for image for touchscreen (1920 x 1080 resolution)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, svg, png

I have these PDF files and they are 4500px x 6646px and 300 resolution and I need to display it on a touchscreen....on this touchscreen you have the ability to zoom in and zoom out. I have converted the PDF to png and when I display it on the touchscreen it looks a little blurry / pixelated when not zoomed in, but when I zoom it its clear as day. My question what size or format would look best on touchscreen that is 1920 x 1080 resolution? So it looks clear as day both zoomed in or zoomed out? I have tried svg same result....I have access to inDesign, Illustrator and Photoshop.....Does anyone have any suggestions?

I have tried using Inkscape, but it does not work well on Macs.

PS - The PDFs are one site plan and bunch for floor plans.

Comment: Why can't you use the PDFs? Have you tried SVG?

Comment: Because I am building a Windows Application and they do not allow iframe's...yes I have tried svg's I am just not at all experienced in image formating, so what I am looking for a step by step way to either use Illustrator or Photoshop or InDesign to properly save them as svg....

Comment: There's no step by step: open in Illustrator and save as SVG. Are there raster images in the PDF or is everything vector?

Comment: As mentioned above – the optimal solution would probably be to save as SVG from Illustrator if that is possible.
If you need to use PNG and the problem is that it looks fuzzy in 100% view after exporting from Illustrator, I would try to open the PDF in Photoshop rather than Illustrator, and "Save as ..." (or Export) to PNG from there. I have found that not all Adobe programs handle export to raster images very well.

Answer (score -1):

[**Adobe Illustrator**](https://www.adobe.com/it/products/illustrator.html), [**Adobe InDesign**](https://www.adobe.com/products/indesign/free-trial-download.html) both handle vector art, so does [**Sketch**](https://www.sketch.com/) app (though it's more of a UI design tool now), so do [**Affinity Designer**](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/designer/) and [**Affinity Publisher**](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/publisher/) - ***all*** of which are available for Mac - I also use Inkscape (on occasion) on a Mac, and as long as you've an X11 instance, it works fine.

For myself, *I'd do this work* in [**Affinity Designer**](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/designer/) myself.

I'd plan on using `.svg`s as your display art format, as it allows scaling / zooming without any resolution or pixelization issues, *assuming all vector content*.

If you *do* have *raster* art embedded in that `.pdf`, I'd redraw it as sheer vector - that way your `.svg` won't ***have*** any raster content to get pixelated.

Hope that helps.